# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.Realm" -- aar package

Tags: android, realm

I have successfully created an `aar` package from an Android module.
It includes Realm.
I've created another sample app and I'm using the `aar` as a dependency inside it. However, whenever I try to run the project, it crashes.

```
  Process: com.example.abhil.myapplication, PID: 3352
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio / realm / Realm;
  at ai.quinto.business.App.onCreate(App.java: 42)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1012)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java: 4553)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java: 151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1364)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 698)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn 't find class "io.realm.Realm" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.abhil.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java: 56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java: 511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java: 469)
  at ai.quinto.business.App.onCreate(App.java: 42) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1012) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java: 4553) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java: 151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1364) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5254) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 903) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 698) 
  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.realm.Realm
  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java: 781)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java: 841)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java: 504)...13 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader;
  no stack available
  07 - 21 09: 19: 13.400 1159 - 1159 / ? E / EGL_emulation : tid 1159: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004(EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

AAR does not include dependencies. You should generate POM file, if you upload your library to Maven repository. Or provide instructions for connecting your library from local AAR

Comment: Hi there, Can you please explain what exactly to do when using local aars in this case? Or any suitable links would be helpful.. thanks

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga You should manually specify all dependencies from library POM or you can put AAR+POM in your Maven repository

Comment: thanks for quick reply. In case of manually adding, Can you please tell how exactly to do it? Thanks.

Comment: just add each dependency from POM as `<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>`